# How to specify multiple ranges for an if statement in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

```
    for counter := 1 to lengthofpassword do
  begin
    currentletter:=password[counter];
    currentascii:=Ord(currentletter);
    if (96<currentascii<123) OR (64<currentascii<91) OR (47<currentascii<58) then
    Writeln('valid')
    else
    asciicheck:=false;
  end;
```

I know this code is wrong but I did it to explain what I want to ask. How can you specify ranges for an if statement? Before, I messed around with lots of if statements and my code wasn't working the way I wanted it to. Basically, I am making a procedure which checks the user input for anything other than uppercase and lowercase alphabet and numbers. This question is different because I was looking for how this problem could be solved using a Case Of statement.

```
    for counter := 1 to lengthofpassword do
  begin
    currentletter:=password[counter];
    currentascii:=Ord(currentletter);
    if (currentascii<48) AND (currentascii>57) then
    asciipoints:=asciipoints+1;
    if (currentascii<65) AND (currentascii>90) then
    asciipoints:=asciipoints+1;
    if (currentascii<97) AND (currentascii>122) then
    asciipoints:=asciipoints+1;
    Writeln(asciipoints);
  end;
```

I also tried to do it like this but then realised this wouldn't work because if one statement was satisfied, the others wouldn't be and the points based system wouldn't work either.

Comment: What is the current topic of your course? Are there any requirements how you need to solve this task? Otherwise you might want to look into set of char.

Comment: Cheers for that, I ended up using  a case of statement using sets like 97..122 for the alphabet

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Glad you found the answer yourself.

Another way to make sure the password only contains upper and lower case characters and numbers is what I tried to point to: define a [`set`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Sets) of characters that are valid and check if each character in your password is [`in`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Expressions_(Delphi)#Set_Operators) these valid characters.

So with a set defined like this:

```
const 
  ValidChars = ['A'..'Z', 'a'..'z', '0'..'9'];
```

you can use statements like

`if password[I] in ValidChars then`

This statement will however generate a compiler warning in Unicode Delphi, as the type in a set is limited to 256 possible values, and their ordinalities must fall between 0 and 255. This isn't the case for WideChar with 65.536 values. So the `set of char` defined is in fact a `set of AnsiChar`. For this task this is acceptable, as every character that needs to be checked is ASCII, so using the function [`CharInSet`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.SysUtils.CharInSet) will not generate a compiler warning and have a defined behavior - returning `False` - if the password contains Unicode characters.

This is the resulting code:

```
const 
  ValidChars = ['A'..'Z', 'a'..'z', '0'..'9'];
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 1 to passwordlength do
  begin
    if CharInSet(password[I], ValidChars) then  
      Writeln('valid')  // more likely to do nothing and invert the if statement
    else
    begin
      asciicheck := False;
      Break; // No need to look further, the check failed
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: `'!'..'/'` should be similar to what you would have done with e.g. 33..47. I can't verify at the moment, so this is not tested. That does not include | and the pound symbol I think.

Comment: Legend, this works like a charm now that I have added all my allowed symbols to that set. I ended up adding them individually.

Comment: This really is the proper solution for the task. Glad you chose it as the accepted answer.

Comment: `CharInSet` function should be used for Unicode Delphi to resolve W1050 compiler warning. But I agree with @Jerry. I'd prefer this way for its readability.

Comment: Thank you @Victoria I hadn't used Delphi typing the initial answer, but now verified and  used your input to revise my answer.

Comment: You're welcome! I missed one more thing none of the answers consider here. It's breaking the loop when you find an invalid char. `asciicheck` variable without it gets the validation output of the last character in the string. `asciicheck := CharInSet(password[passwordlength], ValidChars)` would esentially do the same without a loop.

Comment: @Victoria that mistake was neither in the question nor in any other answer, I introduced that by changing the original code too much. Good catch!

Answer (score 6):

Multiple ranges is best expressed in a `case` statement:

```
begin
  for counter := 1 to lengthofpassword do
  begin
    case Ord(password[counter]) of
      48..57,
      65..90,
      97..122 :
        Writeln('valid')
      else
        asciicheck:=false;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

---

Now, this works for characters < #128. If you are working in a unicode application and don't want the restriction of characters being the english alphabet, it is possible to use [TCharHelper.IsLetterOrDigit](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Character.TCharHelper.IsLetterOrDigit).

```
if password[counter].IsLetterOrDigit then ...
```

Comment: Thanks, this is basically what I came up with.

Comment: Why not simply `if Ord(Password[counter]) in [48..57, 65..90, 97..122] then`? Looks simpler to me. Note that the set will be compiled as constant.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, in case you did not know, the compiler generates the same code in both cases. So it is more a personal preference which solution to chose.

Comment: Even if the resulting code is the same, the intent of an `if` like that is far clearer then a one-tag case statement, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to a comment up above, I have found a solution. I ended up using a Case Of statement like this:

```
    for counter := 1 to lengthofpassword do
  begin
    currentletter:=password[counter];
    currentascii:=Ord(currentletter);
      case currentascii of
        97..122 : asciicheck:=true;
        65..90  : asciicheck:=true;
        48..57  : asciicheck:=true;
        else asciicheck:=false;
      end;
  end;
```

Thanks once again.